# Custom exceptions not working

Tags: java, exception, throw

I am trying to create two exceptions, one that is thrown when the month number is greater than 12 or less than 1, and another that is thrown when the month name is invalid. I thought that I included all the necessary steps ( I'm bad at exceptions ), but my main class is still not working. Any insight as to what I did wrong?

```
public class Month {
private int monthNumber;

/**
 * Creates a new month set to January
 */
public Month(){
    monthNumber = 1;
}

/**
 * Creates a month set to the month number provided by the user
 * @param m the number of the month
 */
public Month(int m) throws MonthsNumberException{
    if (m<1 || m>12){
       throw new MonthsNumberException("Number has to be greater than 1 and less than 12");
    }else{
        monthNumber = m;
    }
}

/**
 * Creates a month based on the string name provided
 * @param m String values for the name of the month
 */
public Month(String m) throws MonthsNameException{
    switch(m){
        case "January":
            monthNumber = 1;
            break;
        case "February":
            monthNumber = 2;
            break;
        case "March":
            monthNumber = 3;
            break;
        case "April":
            monthNumber = 4;
            break;
        case "May":
            monthNumber = 5;
            break;
        case "June":
            monthNumber = 6;
            break;
        case "July":
            monthNumber = 7;
            break;
        case "August": 
            monthNumber = 8;
            break;
        case "September":
            monthNumber = 9;
            break;
        case "October":
            monthNumber = 10;
            break;
        case "November":
            monthNumber = 11;
            break;
        case "December":
            monthNumber = 12;
            break;
                default:
    throw new MonthsNameException("Invalid month name: " + m);
    }
}

/**
 * changes the month to the number provided
 * @param m the number of the month
 */
public void setMonthNumber(int m) throws MonthsNumberException{
    if (m<1 || m>12){
        throw new MonthsNumberException("Number has to be greater than 1 and less than 12");

    }else{
        monthNumber = m;
    }
}

/**
 * returns the number of the month
 * @return the number of the month
 */
public int getMonthNumber(){
    return monthNumber;
}

/**
 * returns the name of the month
 * @return the name of the month
 */
public String getMonthName(){
    String month="";

    switch(monthNumber){
        case 1:
            month = "January";
            break;
        case 2:
            month = "February";
            break;
        case 3:
            month = "March";
            break;
        case 4:
            month = "April";
            break;
        case 5:
            month = "May";
            break;
        case 6:
            month = "June";
            break;
        case 7:
            month = "July";
            break;
        case 8:
            month = "August";
            break;
        case 9:
            month = "September";
            break;
        case 10:
            month = "October";
            break;
        case 11:
            month = "November";
            break;
        case 12:
            month = "December";
            break;

    }
    return month;
}

/**
 * returns a string representation of the month
 * @return the name of the month
 */
public String toString(){
    return getMonthName();
}

/**
 * if the two items are the same returns true
 * @param m the month object to compare
 * @return true if they are the same, false if not
 */
public boolean equals(Month m){
    if (m.getMonthNumber() == this.getMonthNumber()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * If this calling item is after the month object passed as argument returns true
 * @param m the month object
 * @return true if calling object greater, false of argument greater
 */
public boolean greaterThan(Month m){
    if (this.getMonthNumber()>m.getMonthNumber()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * If this calling item is before the month object passed as argument returns true
 * @param m the month object
 * @return true if calling object less than, false of argument less than
 */
public boolean lessThan(Month m){
    if (this.getMonthNumber()<m.getMonthNumber()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
class MonthsNumberException extends Exception
{
    public MonthsNumberException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }
}
class MonthsNameException extends Exception
{
    public MonthsNameException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

}

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MonthDemo {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a month number");
    int mNumber = Integer.parseInt(response);

    Month m1 = new Month(mNumber);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, m1.toString());

    response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a month name");
    Month m2 = new Month(response);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, m2.toString());

}
```

}

Comment: You have to define "not working"

Comment: Any hints as to what the error is?   An error message?  A stack trace?  A behaviour?

Comment: what about it doesn't work? Does it compile? If so, what's the error you're getting or how's the behavior you're getting different from what you expect?

Comment: The main class has a bunch of errors and wont run until the exceptions are working

Comment: Can you tell us _exactly_ which errors?

Comment: Yes, when I started creating those exceptions, one of the lines now has a red squigly line.

Month m2 = new Month(response);

Comment: Why are you creating custom exceptions? Custom exceptions are not recommended to check user input.

Comment: The assignment was for me to create a custom exception, in order to make the main method work. So far, I created those two exceptions but the main method still does not work.

Comment: @user2288575 So a line of code in a method you haven't shown us gives you a "squiggly red line". My 1988 copy of vi doesn't show squiggly red lines, so I have no idea what you are talking about. Perhaps you have one of those new fangled IDES and the question is about what a squiggly red line means in that IDE?

Comment: Where is your main class? It will help to see it...

Comment: I have posted the main method, CodeCamper.

Comment: Eating dinner if no one answers when I'm done I will pop the code in eclipse and check it out.

Comment: Thank you camper, I would greatly appreciate it. This exception stuff is not clicking with me, I've re watched the class lecture 2-3 times already.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html

Comment: @user2288575 Can't you try with a simpler program to make sure you really understand how to use exception at least in a basic manner?  And, I simply can't understand why you can't simply give the error message you are facing.  Why would any one need to copy your code and find that out by themselves?

Comment: The error I'm getting is that the program is compiled with errors. Under the red squigly line it says "unreported exception Month.MonthNamesException; must be caught or declared to be thrown"

Comment: @user2288575 you will continue to get that error until you put a try catch in the Main method because you are throwing exceptions now in the methods it is accessing.

Comment: @user2288575 I correct myself above, you are creating a "checked" exception which means you HAVE TO catch it in the Main method, because your homework does not allow you to change the Main Method the only sensible thing to do is to create an "unchecked" Exception. I updated my answer below to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem #1: You have to throw exceptions where Month is changed.
>
> Problem #2: You are not allowed to catch the exception in the Main
> method.

After fully understanding your homework I have a shortened solution for you. When you extend Exception this is called a "checked" Exception which means you HAVE to surround it in a try catch, but if you extend RuntimeException(also Error) it will allow you to execute the method in the Main thread without handling it. The consequence of this is your program will shutdown if the Exception is thrown, but that seems to be the desired result of your homework. Take your code as it is in your original question and just change this.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MonthsNumberException extends RuntimeException {
    public MonthsNumberException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MonthsNameException extends RuntimeException {
    public MonthsNameException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

This should resolve your homework problem.

Comment: I am actually not allowed to change the main method, only to change the class. Sorry for wasting your time CodeCamper

Comment: @user2288575 you will continue to get that error until you put a try catch in the Main method because you are throwing exceptions now in the methods it is accessing. Either you remove your exception throws or you put a try catch in the main.

Comment: Thanks CodeCamper for your reply.
"You will then alter the Month class to throw that exception anywhere where the month number can be changed"
This is what the instructions say to do.
Which exception throws do I need to delete in my class, since I am not able to change the main method.

Comment: @user2288575 any method that throws an exception has to be surrounded in a try catch. So you can't add exceptions without adding the try catch when it is used(such as in your Main method). I edited my answer to show you how you can throw an exception and then catch it inside of the same method. Sort of like filling a bucket of water only to pour it on the ground. Your homework cannot be sensibly done without changing the Main method unless there is something very fundamental we are missing here.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Now I need to be able to do that exact thing with the Month Names, but it wont allow me to put the whole part of that code in the "try" section.

Comment: @user2288575 I think I figured out what your homework is asking for. You need to extend RuntimeException instead of Exception as I have shown above and your original code will run as I think you intended it to without changing the Main Method.

Comment: @user2288575 It does work, I copy and pasted your entire code into eclipse and I only changed what I showed you above. It works. If you enter an incorrect number it will crash the program and post your Exception to the console. If you enter a correct number and month name the program runs fine. Recopy and paste your code from your original post and just change `extends Exception` to `extends RuntimeException`.

Comment: Thank you code camper. I tried all of that it still doesnt work in NetBeans, I thank you for all your help tho, I will turn it in as is to see if I can get partial credit. Maybe 10 percent.

Comment: @user2288575 It should work in netbeans, did you extend RuntimeException? What error do you get after saving?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried your code, and as you haven't told us the exact error, I am simply guessing here.

You have mentioned that the line `Month m2 = new Month(response);` is having problem.

`Month(int)` constructor is throwing a checked exception.  However, your main method, which is the caller of this constructor, is not doing any proper handling.  You should either `catch` it, or declare your main method to `throws MonthsNumberException`.

---

And please, don't simply throw out a big piece of code and "ask" question like this.  There are lot of things you should do:

1. Have a simplified program to verify your understanding, and to demonstrate your problem.  How is the `lessThan` method relates to  the problem?  You should remove all those "noise" from your question so that people can stay focus in your problem
2. You should give enough information.  If there is an error, tell us the error message, or symptoms of the problem.  Just throw out a big piece of code is not helping.